# belongs_to with accepts_the_nested_attributes for is not saving foreign key in object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations, belongs-to

I have a model named `Profile` which has `belongs_to` relation with `Address`

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :address, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, allow_destroy: true
```

here is the code in controller

```
 def create
        @profile =  Profile.new(profile_signup_params)
        @profile.save
  respond_to
       ..... etc.....
 end
```

for params

```
def profile_signup_params
    params.require(:profile).permit( { address_attributes: [:country] 
end
```

but `@profile.save`

i get this object

```
#<MemberProfile:0x0000000af135b0
 id: 28,
 address_id: nil,
 birth_date: nil,
 country_code: nil,
 phone: nil,
 stripe_customer_id: "123",
 created_at: some time,
 updated_at: some time>
```

as you cane see this `address_id` is `nil`

`Profile` is created
`Address` is created

but `Address` is not assigned to `Profile`

Please help me, what thing i am doing wrong

Comment: can you post the controller code for `new`

Comment: Can you also show full string for profile_signup_params. It looks like problem there...

Answer (score 1):

I think You made a Wrong association between **`Address and Profile`**

*Profile which has `belongs_to` relation with `Address`*  instead It should be Profile has `has_one` association with respect to `Address`.

As mention in official Documentation [Active Record Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_one :address, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, allow_destroy: true
...
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :profile
end
```

Rest Controller and model code would be same in your case except you need to a primary-foreign key relation between **Address** and **Profile**; need to create profile_id column in address table.

**Note:**   Make sure if there is a uniqueness you need to follow [Uniqueness Gotcha!!! in ActiveRecord  NestedAttributes.](http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2015/05/04/uniqueness-gotcha/)

Original Blog [Uniqueness Gotcha!!! Problem and Solution](https://railscoding.wordpress.com/2015/04/27/uniqueness-gotcha/)

Hope this This Help you!!!

Comment: @vinay thanks for your efforts i have voted it. But in my case i want `belongs_to` relation of `profile`  with `address`. I want to store `foreign_key` in `profile` and want to be able to use that `address` for any other model too

Answer (score 1):

To add to `Vinay`'s answer (which is correct IMO), you'd want to make sure you're passing the right data through your controller.

Whilst the `belongs_to` association should allow you to set the nested parameters you require, it would be prudent to mention what `Vinay` said -- if you're creating an `Address` for a `Profile`, surely it would be the `address` that would *belong* to the `Profile`?

You can see about the [`has_one` association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association) here:

[image]

---

You'd handle it in a very similar way:

```
#app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @profile = Profile.new
      @profile.build_address
   end

   def create
      @profile = Profile.new profile_params
      @profile.save
   end

   private

   def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(address_attributes: [:country])
   end
end

#app/views/profiles/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :address do |a| %>
      <%= a.text_field :country %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This, with the model code from `Vinay` should get it working properly.

Comment: thanks for your efforts. In my case i want to store foreign_key in profile and want to be able to use that address for any other model too